# How to implement material lite steppers in Angular2

Tags: angular, material-design-lite

**UPDATE**: basically no material styles are being applied. I tried with toggle and slider but it doesn't work.

I have an angular2 project created with CLI and I am using material lite for styling.

What is the correct way to add and use ***mdl-stepper*** in my project?

I followed instructions here (https://github.com/ahlechandre/mdl-stepper) but my stepper component wouldn't load as shown in the demo.

My app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MDL } from './MaterialDesignLiteUpgradeElement';
import 'hammerjs';


import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component'

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    MDL
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In my styles.css I have:

```
@import '~material-design-lite/dist/material.blue-deep_orange.min.css';
@import '~mdl-stepper/stepper.css';
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons'
```

And in my angular-cli.json I have:

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/material-design-lite/material.min.js",
        "../node_modules/mdl-stepper/stepper.min.js"
      ],
```

HTML looks like following:

```
<ul class="mdl-stepper mdl-stepper--horizontal" id="demo-stepper-nonlinear">
    <li class="mdl-step">
        <span class="mdl-step__label">
            <span class="mdl-step__title">
                <span class="mdl-step__title-text">Core goal</span>
                <span class="mdl-step__title-message">Summarize if needed</span>
            </span>
        </span>
        <div class="mdl-step__content">
            <h2>sample 1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-step__actions">
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored mdl-button--raised" data-stepper-next>
                Continue
            </button>
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" data-stepper-cancel>
                Cancel
            </button>
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" data-stepper-back disabled>
                Back
            </button>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="mdl-step">
        <span class="mdl-step__label">
            <span class="mdl-step__title">
                <span class="mdl-step__title-text">Images</span>
                <span class="mdl-step__title-message">Summarize if needed</span>
            </span>
        </span>
        <div class="mdl-step__content">
            <h2>Sample 2</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-step__actions">
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored mdl-button--raised" data-stepper-next>
                Continue
            </button>
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" data-stepper-cancel>
                Cancel
            </button>
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" data-stepper-back>
                Back
            </button>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="mdl-step">
        <span class="mdl-step__label">
            <span class="mdl-step__title">
                <span class="mdl-step__title-text">Sub goals</span>
                <span class="mdl-step__title-message">Summarize if needed</span>
            </span>
        </span>
        <div class="mdl-step__content">
            <h2>Sample 3</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-step__actions">
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored mdl-button--raised" data-stepper-next>
                Continue
            </button>
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" data-stepper-cancel>
                Cancel
            </button>
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" data-stepper-back>
                Back
            </button>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

***UPDATE***: If I remove stepper.css from styles.css then results looks like following:
[image]

With stepper.css: (buttons and content is gone)

[image]

Comment: Try to add the styles in index.html

Comment: But angular2 cli version expects to add them in styles.css file as a good practice, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, You can add to angularcli.json But just for debugging

Comment: I tried that, and for stepper css it gives me 404 error- `GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/mdl-stepper/stepper.min.css`. <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/mdl-stepper/stepper.min.css"> in my index.html

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/mdl-stepper/stepper.min.css">

Comment: Still same error. I am updating my question with app.module.ts I realized I have angular material and material lite both.

Comment: I added `is-active` to the first step and it is now showing contents and buttons for the first step. However, on clicking continue nothing happens

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

My entire `<ul>` element was inside a div which has `*ngIf` constraint. Strangly, when I removed that constraint, my stepper started looking correct. I do not know why.